# 404 NOT FOUND but web.php routes are declared

Tags: php, laravel

There is a 404 NOT FOUND at web.php for navbar.blade.php:

```
<li class="{{Request::is('home') ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="{{ route('home')}}">Home</a></li>
<li class="{{Request::is('about') ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="{{ route('about')}}">About</a></li>
<li class="{{Request::is('contact') ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="{{ route('contact')}}">Contact</a></li>
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/home', 'PagesController@getHome')->name('home');;
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@getAbout')->name('about');;
Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@getContact')->name('contact');

Route::get('/messages', 'MessagesController@getMessages')->name('messages');

Route::post('/contact/submit', 'MessagesController@submit')->name('submit');
```

PagesController.php:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function getHome(){
        return view('home');
    }
    public function getAbout(){
        return view('about');
    }
    public function getContact(){
        return view('contact');
    }
}
```

Running commands like:

> composer dumpautoload && php artisan view:clear && php artisan
> cache:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan config:clear

Even if is declare at web.php the routes can not be found.

Comment: Did you read all of the [Upgrade Guides](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade)?

Comment: replace: `'PagesController@getHome'` with `[PagesController::class, 'getHome']`

Comment: 404 not found for what URL?

Comment: run the command `php artisan route:list` to check your declared routes

Comment: @CornelRaiu I did both, I ran the list and replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested on a local Laravel instance and I can't get routes to work like you have them.

Also, looking in the [Laravel 8 release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates) You will see that:

> In previous releases of Laravel, the RouteServiceProvider contained a
> $namespace property. This property's value would automatically be
> prefixed onto controller route definitions and calls to the action
> helper / URL::action method. In Laravel 8.x, this property is null by
> default. This means that no automatic namespace prefixing will be done
> by Laravel.

Even though:

> This change only affects new Laravel 8.x applications. Applications
> upgrading from Laravel 7.x will still have the $namespace property in
> their RouteServiceProvider.

Just to cross this one off the list, your routes definition code should look like this.

```
Route::get('/home', [PagesController::class, 'getHome'])->name('home');
Route::get('/about', [PagesController::class, 'getAbout'])->name('about');
Route::get('/contact', [PagesController::class, 'getContact'])->name('contact');

Route::get('/messages', [MessagesController::class, 'getMessages'])->name('messages');

Route::post('/contact/submit', [MessagesController::class, 'submit'])->name('submit');
```

Also, the checks for the routes should be done with:
`Route::is('home')` and not `Request::is('home')`.

Comment: Unfortunally and it is strange does not happen nothing. When I did that an error appears: In Container.php line 875:

  Target class [PagesController] does not exist.